# can we use elastic search on mongo DB?

Tags: database, mongodb, elasticsearch, search, data-analysis

As a Web Developer everyday we are hearing about new technologies, recently I came to know about Elastic Search it is used to analyze the big volumes of data. I've my data in **Mongo DB** weather it is possible to use elastic search on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MongoDB Atlas has a feature called 'Atlas Search', which implements the Apache Lucene engine.  This could be a solution for your search requirements.

See [Atlas Search](https://www.mongodb.com/atlas/search) for details

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you mean by "analyze the big volumes of data", what are your  requirements? Don't pay to much attention on marketing slogans. Maybe you can connect Elasticsearch with MongoDB via an ODBC driver. Elasticsearch is a document oriented NoSQL database like MongoDB is. As usual both have their pros and cons.

MongoDB is more like a **database**, i.e. it supports CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) operations and the [Aggregation Framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) is very powerful.

In Elasticsearch you can store data and analyze or query it. I remember in earlier releases it was not so easy to delete or update existing single documents.